Test in R for stationarity (not for unit root) of a time series
I'm teaching a time series analysis course. We discuss stationarity as a concept, and then our textbook explains the Augmented Dickey Fuller test, which in R is carried out by the command adf.test(). Unfortunately, many non-stationary time series fail to have a unit root, so the ADF test will correctly conclude "no unit root" and students are led to believe the time series is stationary.
Last time I taught the course, I used the kpss.test as an alternative, encouraging students to run both tests, to check two different ways their given time series could fail to be stationary (as well as graphing it, looking at the variability, etc.). Unfortunately, plenty of non-stationary time series can pass both of these tests like for example the AR(1) process $x_t = - x_{t-1} + w_t$ where $w_t$ is white noise, or the AR(2) process $x_t = -x_{t-2} + w_t$.
Poking around online I learned about the Priestley-Subba Rao (PSR) test that used to be available in the R library fractal but it's been depreciated now.
Are there other tests for stationarity that I can share with my students, that are easily available in R packages? I don't need the Phillips–Perron pp.test because that's just another unit root test.

By contemplating a collection of tests, you reveal you're actually doing exploratory data analysis.  Why not admit that and explore the data graphically rather than limiting yourself to hypothesis tests?  There are simple, intuitive, basic methods to do so, such as plotting lagged scatterplots obtained from initial and final segments of the data.

@whuber Oh yes, certainly EDA. And that's why the first step is to plot the time series looking for trend, or for variance changing over time. But it's much harder to see if the autocorrelation structure is changing over time. I am aware that, creating an ACF plot and looking for a too-slow decay is another way to look for non-stationarity. If you can suggest other visual methods beyond these, please, please do so in an answer. I like the lagged scatterplot idea already.

Also, I guess the issue with $x_t = - x_{t-1} + w_t$ is that the variance is blowing up over time. But it's hard to "see" that from a time series plot. If you can suggest a way to visualize that please do. Perhaps to simulate 1000 of these processes and keep track of where they reach over time?

I'm not suggesting an ACF: for that it's useless.  Instead, plot lagged scatterplots, such as $(x_t, x_{t+1}),$ separately for the beginning (say first third) and end (last third) of the data.  The reason for omitting part of the middle is to reduce the effects of serial correlation.  BTW, if you can simulate a process, you likely are making such strong assumptions that you could select an appropriate formal hypothesis test.

The way I've been teaching this (to early undergrads with just one previous course in prob/stat) is heavy on simulation. So the first step was to simulate many processes and then investigate which are stationary and why, without the math (which is hard for these students) of computing autocorrelations by hand. What would be an appropriate formal hypothesis test to catch these two series that escaped the adf.test and kpss.test?

I like the simulation approach and have used it even when teaching professionals (such as college professors).  But I can't answer your follow-up question, because it depends on what model you adopt for the time series process.

Decpreciated --> deprecated?

@whuber For a stationary process, we simulate using for example y=arima.sim(n=500,list(ar=0.9),innov=rnorm(500)). For a non-stationary process, arima.sim() refuses to simulate, so we do for example w = rnorm(250 + 50); x = stats::filter(w, filter=c(1.2), method="recursive")[-(1:50)] (for burn-in reasons). Not sure if this is what you meant by the model for the time series process. I'm doing the simplest possible model. Just normal white noise.

For examples of unusual models (and some ways to analyze them) see my posts at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/384874, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14842, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18538/, and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/410534.
